# calculate distance live and order asc|desc

Tags: sql, distance, live

So when i start the web app, the server gets the user geolocation and save it as variable (latitude/longitude)
I've got a database with: ID, Name, Latitude, Longitude

Now i want to select all entries from the database and order them by distance

I know how to calculate the distance between coordinates, but i dont know how to order things "live"

Can you guys give me a hint how to solve this?

Comment: Okay i think i found the solution by myself ;) Will post the code when it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply specify the distance calculation (say for example its (Longitude + Latitude) divided by 42) in the `order by` clause

```
select ID, Name, Latitude, Longitude, (Longitude + Latitude) / 42 as Distance
  from YourTable
 order by (Longitude + Latitude) / 42
```

However, because the distance calculation is likely to be slightly more complex than (Longitude + Latitude) / 42, you might want to consider ordering your results based on the ordinal of the column in the result set (I think most databases support this). So something like.....

```
select ID, Name, Latitude, Longitude, /* Insert Distance Calculation Here */ as Distance
  from YourTable
 order by 5  -- Column ordinals are 1-based
```

You should note though that there are some gotchas to this approach. For example, if the order of the columns are changed or columns are added, the `order by` ordinal must also be changed or you will see unexpected results. Obviously if you order by field name or calculation this isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT id,name,latitude,longitude, <Your_formula> distance from <table_name> order by distance
```

Here's sqlfiddle for that

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66644/2

Comment: You learn something new every day - is this widely supported or only in newer databases, I'm sure I've tried that with other databases and it has not worked. (SQL Server 2005 possibly?) I see it works with 2012 though.